# MPI program causes "invalid MIT-magic-cookie-1 key" warning to show

Tags: x11, python, mpi, xauth

I'm setting up a new development environment that requires high performance computing. I installed mpi and openmpi on this new machine (Ubuntu 20.04), and I wrote the following code in python as a sort of "hello world" style test.

```py
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()


print(f"Hi, I'm proccessor {rank} out of {size}")
```

And then I run this the normal way I would an mpi enabled python script (note: it's called '1.py'):

```
mpirun -n 4 python 1.py
```

The script runs fine, but it always opens with a warning message, "invalid MIT-magic-cookie-1 key". The full output is:

```
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyHi, I'm proccessor 0 out of 4
Hi, I'm proccessor 1 out of 4
Hi, I'm proccessor 2 out of 4
Hi, I'm proccessor 3 out of 4
```

If it helps, I'm using proprietary chipset drivers, and my processor is an Intel® Core™ i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz × 8.
This isn't impeding my work, but I do find it annoying as heck. Any ideas?

Most of the information I could find online had to do with SSH issues and remote servers and whatnot, but this is just running locally on my laptop.

Comment: MIT-MAGIC-COOKIEs are used by X11 clients to authenticate to a server. If mpi doesnt do graphics try unsetting DISPLAY in your environment before running the program, or look for use of `xauth` in your .profile or .bash* and so on.

Comment: Okay, I ran `unset DISPLAY` and that didn't change anything. I also read through .profile and all of the .bash* and couldn't find any lines that reference `xauth`.

Comment: I have the same problem which started when I updated to Ubuntu 20.04.1.

Comment: Ever found a solution? I have the same problem.